# Count the sum of text box values + the value of jQuery UI Slider

Tags: jquery, textbox, count, jquery-ui-slider

Here's a quick look what I'm trying to do: http://jsfiddle.net/Klisee/u7tw0qwp/12/

Basically I'm trying to do the following: Add the jQuery UI slider right next to the top box. Then give the top box the value of the slider * 2 (easy part). And finally give the bottom box the value of ALL the boxes. And all this in real time as I scroll the slider or press the check boxes.

My jQuery UI slider is simple, nothing fancy:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#slider" ).slider({
      range: "min",
      value: 0,
      min: 0,
      max: 100,
      slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $("#sliderValue").val(ui.value * 2); 
      }
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are a working fiddle for your problem :)
http://jsfiddle.net/u7tw0qwp/14/

```
$('#checkbox1').click(function(){
if (this.checked) {
    $('#textbox1').val(30);
    updateTotal();
}
else {
  $('#textbox1').val(0);
  updateTotal();
}
});
$('#checkbox2').click(function(){
if (this.checked) {
    $('#textbox2').val(40);
    updateTotal();
}
else {
  $('#textbox2').val(0);
  updateTotal();
}
});
function updateTotal(){
var total = 0;
$('.textboxes').each(function() {
  total += Number($(this).val());
});
$('#totalSum').val(total);
}
updateTotal();

$( "#slider" ).slider({
  range: "min",
  value: 0,
  min: 0,
  max: 100,
  slide: function( event, ui ) {
    $("#sliderValue").val(ui.value * 2); 
      updateTotal();
  }
});
```

Let me know if this is what you are tring to accomplish :)

Comment: You're my new best friend. THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

Add class `textboxes` to your first textbox as well :

Add jquery:

```
$("#sliderValue").blur(function(){
    updateTotal();
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/u7tw0qwp/13/).

**EDIT:**

I think this is what you're looking for:

[New DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/u7tw0qwp/15/).

Comment: Already tried. I doesn't change the value of the final box in real time as the slider is being scrolled.

Comment: what do you exactly mean by "slider", the input box, right?
Can you post the actual code?

Comment: Read the description again.